# Should I build model for every view from DTO

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm quite new to the ASP.NET MVC. I was just wondering that should I build a model for every DTO that I'm going to show data from, or should I just use the DTO in my view? If I use the DTO straight are there going to be any major problems later? Am I going to lose some valuable tools? First thing that crossed my mind is that it's easier to make validation and display name easier, I think that you can also build them in your DTO. In my opinion is that you should build the Model, for every view. But what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982042/dto-viewmodel) will give you some valuable insight