# Where do you convert types in MVC architecture?

Tags: model-view-controller

Where do you do type conversion in MVC if you want to strictly follow the architecture?

For example if the model had an integer and the view needed it as a string to print it, what would be the proper solution?

1. The controller passes the integer to the view, and the view converts it to a string.
2. The controller gets the integer, converts it to a string and then gives that string to the view.
3. The controller asks the model to return the integer as a string and then just passes that string to the view.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in many (most?) "real world" MVC applications, the "View" will often have its own "View Model", separate and distinct from the persistence layer's "Data Model". So there will be "conversions" at several different layers. Here's a good link: [Domain vs DTO vs ViewModel - How and When to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874328)

Answer (score 0):

Read about DTO design pattern, this design pattern is used to pass data between layer in layered architecture. Usually controller converts the model to something that view needs using DTO design pattern.